# Don't allow template literal to contain variable

Tags: javascript

I wish to create a function that takes an argument as a template literal, however will throw an error if the template literal has any variables within the template.

For example the following is valid.

```
const value = checker(`hello world`)
```

However this would throw an error.

```
const value = checker(`hello ${name}`)
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Template literals allow for tagging, it can be achieved like this:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function noVarTemplate(strings, ...values) {
  if (values.length) throw new Error('the noVarTemplate does not allow template literal values')
  return strings[0]
}

const value = noVarTemplate`Hello World`

// const value = noVarTemplate`Hello ${a}`

console.log(value)
```